# Google Chrome on Mac OS X, full screen option is greyed out, why?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome

When I first installed Chrome the menu option for "full screen" was enabled and worked, but for the last few months is been greyed out/disabled.

Is it just me or perhaps there is a bug which is why its disabled?

I tried deleting the installed version and downloading a new copy, to no avail - but perhaps there is a setting in my local preferences that could be disabling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been disabled on all Mac OS X versions for now. You can read more about the disabled features in [this](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/11/30/chrome-for-mac-features/) TechCrunch article.

> Another feature currently disabled in
>   the Mac builds of Chromium is Full
>   Screen mode. It would seem this too
>   has been pushed to M5.